# Unable to resolve class com.android.builder.core.DefaultManifestParser

Tags: java, android, gradle

When i build my android project using gradlew, it failed with this error message

```
  Unable to resolve class com.android.builder.core.DefaultManifestParser
```

is there anybody know why this happen?
Please help, thanks.

Comment: in which ide are you developing?

Comment: @Cheerag i'm using android studio, but when i execute using command line : gradlew assembleDebug, it gives the same message

Comment: invalidate caches and restart android studio. may be resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found that the file build.gradle is missing this script

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
   }

if (gradle.gradleVersion >= "2.2") {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+'
    }
} else if (gradle.gradleVersion >= "2.1") {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.0+'
    }
} else {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.0+'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0+'
    }
}
 }
```

after i added this script, the build process is success.